# WordPress: removing hook actions from a class

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove an action from a hook that is found within a class (from a plugin), however the code is not working.  I know the class name and here is the code:

```
function swa_remove_wc_shipping($instance){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array('FUE_Addon_Woocommerce', 'display_email_subscription_checkbox' ) );
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','swa_remove_wc_shipping');
```

The class name is `FUE_Addon_Woocommerce` and I could find the hook in that class but I am unable to remove the action from it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The actions  are different?   Shouldn't your remove fire on the same action that adds it (or on an action that runs after the action that adds it.  And with a priority that causes it to run AFTER the woo add action?

Comment: Tried changing the add_action to woocommerce_after_order_notes but same result.

Comment: And did you try setting the priority to 99 to force it to fire late, jhopefully after the add?   You could also check whether the action is there before trying to remove it.  If it is not there, then it is probably being added later, after your remove. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_action

Comment: changing the priority did not do anything - but using remove_all_actions( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes' ); does work and removes all action hooks including the one I want to remove.  But I only want to remove the one.

Comment: It sounds like the action is not being referred to correctly then, if re moving all works, then the action you want to remove is there, you just need to refer to it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array('FUE_Addon_Woocommerce', 'display_email_subscription_checkbox' ) );` 
in your functions.php directly, as mentioned in the comments your function may be called before it is added.